# Flipping True or False values to save typing and time

Tags: delphi

I have a few columns in a DBGrid that I want to hide and show at different times depending on what the user wants to view.

Rather than writing the following code;

```
For i := 1 to DBGrid1.Columns.Count -1 do
  Begin

    If DBGrid1.Columns[i].FieldName = 'SOMETHING' then
      Begin
        if DBGrid1.Columns[i].visible then 
        DBGrid1.Columns[i].visible:=false else 
        DBGrid1.Columns[i].visbile:=true;
      End;

    If DBGrid1.Columns[i].FieldName = 'ANOTHERFIELD' then
      Begin
        if DBGrid1.Columns[i].visible then 
        DBGrid1.Columns[i].visible:=false else 
        DBGrid1.Columns[i].visbile:=true;
      End;

    { And so on... for another 8 columns }

  End;
End;
```

I've got the following function;

```
Function Flip(CurrentState:Boolean):Boolean;
Begin

  If CurrentState then
     Result:=False else
     Result:=True;

End;
```

Then I use the function above like this;

```
For i := 1 to DBGrid1.Columns.Count -1 do
  Begin

    If DBGrid1.Columns[i].FieldName = 'SOMETHING' then
    DBGrid1.Columns[i].visible := Flip(DBGrid1.Columns[Loop].visible;

    If DBGrid1.Columns[i].FieldName = 'ANOTHERFIELD' then
    DBGrid1.Columns[i].visible := Flip(DBGrid1.Columns[Loop].visible;

    { And so on... for another 8 columns }

  End;
End;
```

I can't address columns by their index directly because they move around, therefore I use the Field Name associated with it.

My question is this, is there are better and smarter way to hide and unhide many columns?

Comment: I'd replace the if-then-elses with `DBGrid1.Columns[i].Visible := not DBGrid1.Columns[i].Visible`. I.e. use the `not`keyword instead of your `Flip` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd replace the if-then-elses with `DBGrid1.Columns[i].Visible := not DBGrid1.Columns[i].Visible` - i.e. use the `not` keyword instead of your `Flip` function.

And you probably can store references to the relevant columns in an array, TList or similar. Then you don't need to loop **all** columns and check their names.

Comment: I had not considered the Not and it works perfectly. The array or List I'm not going to worry about as there are only a dozen fields to loop through. Thanks.